# Shopify theme app extension doesn't update asset files during the development

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, hot-reload

I'm developing an app for Shopify and I'm trying to make a [theme app extension](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions) according to the official documentation. I start testing my app with the `npm run dev` command. Then, I made an [app block](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions/extensions-framework#app-blocks-for-themes) and activate it in my theme. My [assets](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions/extensions-framework#:%7E:text=Description-,assets,-Contains%20CSS%2C%20JavaScript) works fine and I can see my custom CSS and javascript on my store page. But, the main problem is that changing the styles or scripts in the asset folder doesn't update in my store page, even by reloading the page. The only solution that I found is to stop the terminal and re-run the `npm run dev` command again.

Is there any way to enable hot-reloading in this process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have the necessary dependencies installed. Make sure you have webpack-dev-server or a similar tool installed in your project.
2. Update your development server script in your package.json file to include the --hot flag. Modify the "dev" script to something like this:

> ```
> "scripts": {
>   "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
> }
> ```

The --hot flag enables hot module replacement, which is responsible for injecting updated assets into the running application without requiring a full page reload.

3. Configure your webpack configuration file to enable hot module replacement. You may need to add or update the devServer section in your webpack configuration. Here's an example:

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   // other webpack configuration options
>
>   devServer: {
>     hot: true
>   }
> };
> ```

4. Save your changes and run the npm run dev command again. With hot-reloading enabled, any changes you make to your assets should now be automatically reflected in your store page without the need to manually stop and restart the development server.

Make sure to consult the official documentation of the tools and frameworks you are using for more detailed instructions on how to enable hot-reloading in your specific development environment.

Comment: Thanks. But in the node project package we have this: `"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js --ignore ./frontend",`